# Can't set Network Image with error "Exception caught by image resource service ..."

Tags: image, flutter

Similar types of problems already on this site but in my case, it is different.
Please, take a look at my code and the error. I can't understand the error.

Here is a part of my code which is causing the error:

```
....
....
GridTile(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  Text(feedbackItems[index].name),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Image.network(
                                        '${feedbackItems[index].photo}'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ))
....
....
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 Container(  
  height:100,width:100           // you can give height and width there
  child: Image.network(
  '${feedbackItems[index].photo}', fit: BoxFit.fill,),       
 ),
```

Comment: you can try with height and width in the container .

Comment: please check you are getting url or not  in feedbackItems.

Answer (score 0):

```
BASELINK = 'http://xxxx.com/asset/images/'; //defined baselink
Container(  
  height:100,width:100           // you can give height and width there
  child: Image.network(
  BASELINK+'${feedbackItems[index].photo}', fit: BoxFit.fill,),       
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.